# Auto-populate form script on Wordpress page

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I want my form on a Wordpress page to be able to auto populate the "productid" & "productsku" fields from the url parameter.

The URL parameter looks like this:

```
http://.../?productid=1680&productsku=1
```

My current script works on my other form pages but not this page.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'autopopulate_product_id_script' );
function autopopulate_product_id_script() {
    if( isset( $_GET['productid'] ) ):
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
            $('input[name="productid"]').val("<?php echo $_GET['productid']; ?>");
            $('input[name="productsku"]').val("<?php echo $_GET['productsku']; ?>");
        })(jQuery);
        </script>
        <?php
    endif;
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In your code, java script code is not working when the action is called.

Kindle try below code...

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'autopopulate_product_id_script' );
  function autopopulate_product_id_script() {
    if( isset( $_GET['productid'] ) ):
      ?>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function auto_fill(){
          jQuery('input[name=productid]').val("<?php echo $_GET['productid']; ?>");
          jQuery('input[name=productsku]').val("<?php echo $_GET['productsku']; ?>");
        }
        auto_fill();
      </script>
  <?php
    endif;
}
```